# How to use "ren" or "rename" to truncate the file name until underscored?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have some file names as below saved in `C:\aaa\temp`

Before:

```
92485345_A0027777882244.zip
87493354_A0027684085444.zip
87111901_A0027871905777.zip
```

some fixed rule in the file name:

1. I need to delete the characters until the underscore "_"
2. The name after underscore always begins with `A0027`

Can someone please teach me how to write a script to batch rename them as below:

After:

```
A0027777882244.zip
A0027684085444.zip
A0027871905777.zip
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think what you're looking for is the [PowerShell Split method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of characters in front of the underscore `_` is always the same, then use this:

```cmd
rem // Expecting 8 characters in front of `_`:
ren "????????_A0027*.zip" "/////////*.*"
```

This is an undocumented feature of `ren`, which is described [there](https://superuser.com/a/475875).

---

When the number of characters in front of `_` can vary you have to use [`dir /B`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to get the list of matching files, a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/forcmd.html) to capture it and to split the file names, then [`ren`](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) to finally rename each file:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %E in ('dir /B /A:-D "*_A0027*.zip"') do @ren "%E_%F" "%F"
```

To use this code in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) you need to change `%` to `%%`:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%E in ('dir /B /A:-D "*_A0027*.zip"') do (
    ren "%%E_%%F" "%%F"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

- List the files from the directory.
- Iterate through the list of names.
- Remove chars up until the underscore (including).
- Rename each file to the new name as you iterate through list.

Now, if you chose to do this with a script or pipe through, it is up to you.